# Apache2 restart fails unless I comment out error log lines - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, apache2

I was struggling getting Apache2 to restart after enabling my site until I stumbled on this [post: Apache2 restart failed in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777672/apache2-restart-failed-in-ubuntu-16-04) where I tried one of the solutions listed in comments which suggested commenting out the two log lines.

I've done this and now Apache2 starts again but I'm concerned that my log files will no longer be recoded where I want them to. Why won't apache function when the log lines are not commented out?

See bellow my current configuration with log lines commented out:

```
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public_html
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    #ErrorLog /var/www/html/example.com/log/error.log
    #CustomLog /var/www/html/example.com/log/access.log combined
```

When lines are not commented out I get the following error:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When I run "systemctl status apache2.service" I get the following:

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-01-24 10:08:36 EST; 1h 29min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 23552 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 28665 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 28148 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─28163 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─28513 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─28514 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─28515 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─28516 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─28517 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─28524 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Jan 24 11:34:43 kbo1.kidbo.co apache2[28665]:  * Reloading Apache httpd web server apache2
Jan 24 11:34:43 drop1.example.com apache2[28665]:  *
Jan 24 11:34:43 drop1.example.com apache2[28665]:  * The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anything.
Jan 24 11:34:43 drop1.example.como apache2[28665]: Output of config test was:
Jan 24 11:34:43 drop1.example.com apache2[28665]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/www/html/example.com/log/' for error log of vhost defined at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf:1
Jan 24 11:34:43 drop1.example.com apache2[28665]: AH00014: Configuration check failed
Jan 24 11:34:43 drop1.example.com apache2[28665]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Jan 24 11:34:43 drop1.example.com apache2[28665]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jan 24 11:34:43 drop1.example.com systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
```

Comment: Please, edit your question and paste the error message when log lines are not commented out.

Comment: Thanks. Updated question with original error codes. @SpasSpasov

Comment: This line isn't complete: `Jan 24 11:34:43 drop1.example.com apache2[28665]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/w`. But I suppose you have to create the log directory, maybe it just doesn't exists.

Comment: Realized that and updated @SpasSpasov. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `systemctl status apache2.service` contains next error message:

```
Jan 24 11:34:43 drop1.example.com apache2[28665]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/www/html/example.com/log/' for error log of vhost defined at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf:1
```

It means, you have to create the desired log directory, it just doesn't exists.

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/html/example.com/log/
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Comment: Don't forget to use the real path :)

Comment: Does it work? @Robert

Comment: Thanks @Spas Spasov for forcing me to go through process. Directory was there but was named "logs" instead of "log"

Comment: @Robert If you find this answer helpful, you can accept it. :) http://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: Would love to @Spas Spasov "actually" accept it. In fact, I actually already have. But it seems I don't have enough reputation points (need 15 minimum apparently) to engage in any meaningful way with stack-exchange product suite.  :-(

Comment: They had some technical trouble a while ago. Whatever, @Robert , perhaps the normal state will be restored soon.