# /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so: undefined symbol: ap_map_http_request_error

Tags: apache2

I have [PHP7 installed on my Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04) laptop.
It was working perfectly all this while.
Now, for some reason my apache2 isn't starting.

```
anjanesh@anjanesh-Latitude-3560:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2                                                                                                                  * 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so: undefined symbol: ap_map_http_request_error
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

All the files are in place. There is libphp7.0.so in /usr/lib/apache2/modules.

Comment: Post the apache error log...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zEgZxXjC

Comment: /var/log/apache2/error.log - http://pastebin.com/GmtAXUz9

Comment: Will it be too much to ask that you re-install after a full purge as I did the same from that site and mine is ok...

Comment: I just did sudo-apt-get update and updated the software and it now works.

Comment: Please have a look at the answer of  [FlorianDiesch](https://askubuntu.com/users/2369/florian-diesch) on this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/777672/apache2-restart-failed-in-ubuntu-16-04 -> install libapache2-mod-php7.0

Answer (score 3):

Reinstalled PHP on 16.04 LTS to fix this. Note: after running `apt update` Apache2 would not install until a `sudo apt autoremove` had been run.

## Install Apache

```
sudo aptitude install apache2
```

## Install MySQL

```
sudo aptitude install mysql-server
```

## Install PHP

```
sudo aptitude install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 php7.0-common php7.0-gd php7.0-mysql php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-curl php7.0-intl php7.0-xsl php7.0-mbstring php7.0-zip php7.0-bcmath php7.0-iconv php-mcrypt
```

## Start Apache

```
apachectl start
```

Comment: I think 16.04 has PHP7 by default. In my case, I am using 14.04 and ondrej/php7

Comment: It took me several iterations to find this combination to fix this on my 16.04 machine. One thing I did learn is that it is possible to keep adding on packages or reinstalling packages until it works :)

Comment: Always I use this answer, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not enough reputation to comment ...

Doing `sudo apt-get update` wasn't enough for me (OP's Comment under the question).

But then also doing `sudo apt-get upgrade` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are upgrading your php version using ondrej ppa (sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php). You need to upgrade the apache2 version too.

Please add the below ppa too and upgrade the apache2 package.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install -y apache2
```

Then enable the libapache2-mod-php7.0 or libapache2-mod-php.

```
$ sudo a2enmod php
```

or

```
$ sudo a2enmod php7.0
```

or

```
$ sudo a2enmod php7.1
```

Restart the apache.

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Your problem is solved.